# How to assign standard deviation in bar graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
dt<- fread("Book2.txt")
names(dt)
Book2.txt <- data.frame(table('d$sample','d$expression', 'd$SD'))
names(dt) <- c("sample","expression", "SD")
ticks <- c('wt','clone16','clone14','clone20')
SD <-c(0.001793815,0.000869683,0.000106077,6.04489E-05)
gg <- ggplot(data=dt, aes(x=sample, y=expression)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") 
gg <- gg + scale_x_discrete(limits=ticks, labels = ticks) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=expression-SD, ymax=expression+SD), color= "grey", width=.1)
```

Please, Could anyone help me out in solving this problem.The graph A is obtained using excel from the same set of values, while the graph B is obtained using ggplot2. The SD deviation in the geom_bar graph is not actual and assigned to the graph according to the height of the graph.

My plots: [image]

Comment: The errorbars in ggplot are correct as far as I can see. Your excel plot only has 0.5 SD in either direction.

Comment: @Axeman, How to get the same error bar of SD in ggplot as I have in excel? any idea please

Comment: You can use `geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = expression - 0.5 * SD, ymax = expression+ 0.5 * SD)`, but I doubt that's what you want to do. It is customary (as far as I know) to plot the mean +- SD, which is what your ggplot shows.

Comment: @Axeman, you are just right bro, but the excel graph is also actual graph that's why I want to have the same SD bar as in excel. Thanks for your earlier responses

Comment: +   geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = expression -0.5*SD, ymax = expression +0.5*SD), color= "grey", width=.1) +
+   gg
Error: Don't know how to add o to a plot

Comment: don't add `gg` at the end?

Comment: @Axeman Thanks. Its working now. I deleted the gg at the end